# At which levels do you unlock new showcase slots?

Tags: steam, steam-trading-cards

When you collect trading cards and craft them into badges, you also increase your level.
Each level yields some rewards, like increased friends list size.

So at which levels do you unlock additional showcase slots to display various Steam related things in it, e.g. Achievements or Workshop?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You unlock a showcase [every ten levels, starting at level ten](http://steamcommunity.com/tradingcards/faq).